# Why is it so difficult to set TypeScript Properties until you set them to undefined? TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

This drives me into madness every time I have to deal with it. I cannot tell you the hours of extra coding that I encounter because of this, what I feel, is a flaw of TypeScript.

It does not make any sense to me that I have to set a property to `undefined` in order to then set it with actual values.

here is the example:

```js
// why do i have to do this?
this.aClass.aInterface: ClassAndInterface = {
    aProperty: undefined
}
this.aClass.aInterface.aProperty: ClassAndInterface = {
    name: 'The Name',
    description: 'A description'
};
```

I feel like there should something for this erroring out to set a property that be can be applied to mitigate this error. If I am trying to set the property the fact it is undefined isn't a concern to me especially when the value is optional.

Comment: TypeScript's type system is erased when you complile to JS. In JS you can't write `let x; x.a = 123;` and TS doesn't change that. If you'd provide a [mcve] of your issue I might be able to suggest something that helps. Right now it's not clear what your type definitions are or why you have runtime errors. You generally *don't* have to set optional properties to `undefined`, so I'd be interested in seeing code that demonstrates your problem; ideally code that could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to see what you're seeing.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz thanks I am going to reproduce it and I think I know what I am doing wrong

Comment: see apparently I am not crazy. This is a new feature that alearts you in or as of version 3.9.2 Property 'prop1' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)

Comment: The [`--strictPropertyInitialization` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) has been part of TS since v 2.7.  If you could provide a [mcve] that actually shows why this is bothering you as opposed to helping you I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @jcalz I posted an answer please feel free to edit or add any insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have what I feel is a good answer to why this is occurring and why it may be easier to come across this problem in `TypeScript` versus writing `js` on it's own.

The problem stems from working with classes and objects more readily in Typescript not that you can't obviously do the same thing with js. However, when you start using interfaces and types to interfaces and classes this can be where things have more need for understanding.

The issue truly comes from taking a property to far. People actually post about this exact issue a lot and from what I see it is a misunderstanding in its truest sense.

What's the misunderstanding exactly? As @jcalz posted in the above message

```js
let x; 
x.a = 123 // NO <<< you can't do that
```

It is really that simple. However, when you writing pretty and well formed objects you can quickly do something like this.

```js
x = {
   a: 3
}
x.a = 3; <<< this is OK
```

That is all good and understood so why does `Typescript` constantly get me with that error. The answer is actually when you're trying to be responsible and write classes and interfaces that are typed to properties and you go a level one too far.

What do I mean when I say a level one too far? It's when you try take a base class and or interface and set the property of an interfaced property from that base class. It could be a classed typed property just the same.

At that point you are dealing with a property that technically hasn't been defined.

What should you do that would mitigate the issue and not cause errors or mistakes in your coding?

What you should do is act upon the interface directly with a new property that is set to that interface. You can do the same if it were a class. **Afterwards, you should set the base property to that new property directly that is of the interface and or class.** (this is shown in the code sample below)

Also, and you may need to do this as I found out, you can set the property to undefined. Alarm bells, code smell and caveats come with this approach.

1. You have to set every property in that interface or class to undefined or some value (intiate)
2. You have deal with the fact you set every property upstream to undefined meaning you might not want to carry a bunch of undefined values in your object.
3. A lot of guarding (if statements) and protections are needed downstream so that you don't come across runtime errors
4. It feels like code smell and it probably is
5. What is code smell? I don't know exactly but you should do it I know that and it doesn't actually smell

So, why would you do this as opposed to doing it the right way? Well in my case I was passing along an object from class to class and I was trying to use that exact object that would return again whole.

Instead what I should have done is passed a new object with the base object and new object {base: baseObj, new: newObj} and just returned both of those.

In any event I have included code that [you can go to the playground and play](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAsAFDJXKiRQBiiEAClOgA4CMAXMgM5gooAOYAfAK4gAJhBigIUgNwVqNfAyasOAJgD8vAUJDDl5AL4UKCADZw%20fNFggBhW-ZIrq7cQCNrwBGR2Ni5eDGw8OkIICWlZeSVPKmCdA0ERWJk5EAVTVRT2AGYAQjSjEwoLcmsIMGRrdAQ4ay12ZABeZByAd0dsVzs%20AAoASlMAenHkMAALYAd56fRkTGAwYGE4SGQ4EBp7cQgKSfrG5taAOgLODo9yE9VaaEYkVp5kSSyE46mq8YAqf7IdBQNQCCBwKTIKTLWaLPiwmZbGh1TBwADWEAcmBBKD4EBA%20J20n2OwQCHEUC2KDAiJQTXYcB8wH8YAAnsCYNMZih0D4AFYQBBgChA3ZQ2nIbpIuqLWYoCAAD3YQsgUPQ4jA3jq6C58uBAtVyFF4woNR18qgABkzi0QmEnJECExTOhLTamnaOLcyJRqE8NK8Qu8AOQAFSEAl2IcqVnQhPQNQuDWEQzdPOttsuAZeLGDYzNWZCV2Dt3T0A95xCpgansu1wuOc0pc6IeccCgDT4IdMCHjCKTKaGtarHBLHE4jfUubeBfIfYTg-QqfLmbrxabQYnc9Xla97CndBnLeQbZmkfW0bji4gyeXw6LY%20uYyAA) with the Typescript Editor and see what it is that I am speaking of and what the differences are of doing one method versus the other.

```js
interface SomeInterface {
    interFaceProp1: string|undefined;
    interFaceProp2?: string;
}

class SomeClass {
    public prop1: SomeInterface|undefined;
    prop2: string|undefined;
    prop3!: string;
}
let localProp = new SomeClass();
// this is to mitigate an issue
// localProp.prop1 = {
//     interFaceProp1: undefined
// }
/** or instead do this so that it makes more sense and is accurate to the capability of the object
* and to what is the expected output of the object 
*/
let otherLocalProp: SomeInterface;
otherLocalProp = {
    interFaceProp1: 'Tristan'
}
console.log(otherLocalProp.interFaceProp1);
localProp.prop1 = otherLocalProp;
localProp.prop1.interFaceProp1 = 'Carlos';
console.log(localProp.prop1.interFaceProp1);
console.log(otherLocalProp.interFaceProp1);
otherLocalProp.interFaceProp1 = 'Christian'
console.log(localProp.prop1);
```